# Converting MongoDB's IAsyncCursor(Source) into an Rx Observable Sequence

Tags: c#, asynchronous, mongodb, system.reactive

I've been toying with this idea for quite a while.
Needless to say that this really enables a lot of possibilities,
Especially when combined with a SignalR Backend.

Added below is what I came up with. Would love your input!

EDIT: I know that this code has a "vulnerability":
 the cursor or its source must not be used outside of this extension method for this to really work.
This is handled at a different layer.

```
internal static class MongoRxExtensions
{
    private const int False = 0;
    private const int True = 1;

    public static IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>(this IAsyncCursorSource<T> source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        var obs = CreateCompoundObservable<T>((observable, token) => GetCursorAsync(source, observable, token));
        return Flatten(obs);
    }

    public static IObservable<T> AsObservable<T>(this IAsyncCursor<T> cursor)
    {
        if (cursor == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cursor));

        var obs = CreateCompoundObservable<T>((observable, token) => Task.FromResult(cursor));
        return Flatten(obs);
    }

    private static IObservable<T> Flatten<T>(IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> obs)
    {
        return obs.SelectMany(enumerable=>enumerable.ToObservable());
    }

    private static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> CreateCompoundObservable<T>(Func<IObserver<IEnumerable<T>>, CancellationToken, Task<IAsyncCursor<T>>> source)
    {

        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;
        var disposable = Disposable.Create(() => cts.Cancel());
        int subscribed = False;

        var obs = Observable.Create<IEnumerable<T>>(observer =>
        {
            //Ensure that only the first subscription succeeds.
            if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref subscribed, True) == True)
            {
                observer.OnError(new InvalidOperationException("cursor has already been consumed"));
                return Disposable.Empty;
            }

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {

                var cursorTask = source(observer, token);
                var continuation = cursorTask.ContinueWith((_) => { });
                await continuation;

                if (cursorTask.Exception != null)
                {
                    ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(cursorTask.Exception).Throw();
                }

                if (cursorTask.IsCanceled)
                    return;

                var cursor = cursorTask.Result;

                if(cursor==null)
                    return;

                await EmitAsync(cursor, token, observer);
            });

            return disposable;
        });

        return obs;
    }


    private static async Task<IAsyncCursor<T>> GetCursorAsync<T>(IAsyncCursorSource<T> source, IObserver<IEnumerable<T>> observer, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var cursorTask = source.ToCursorAsync(token);
        //do not pass token to task continuation- ensure serial execution between tasks.
        var continuation = cursorTask.ContinueWith(_ => { });

        await continuation;

        if (cursorTask.Exception != null)
        {
            observer.OnError(cursorTask.Exception);
            return null;
        }

        if (cursorTask.IsCanceled)
            return null;

        IAsyncCursor<T> cursor = cursorTask.Result;
        return cursor;
    }

    private static async Task EmitAsync<T>(IAsyncCursor<T> cursor, CancellationToken token, IObserver<IEnumerable<T>> observer)
    {


        try
        {
            while (token.IsCancellationRequested == false)
            {
                var moveNextTask = cursor.MoveNextAsync(token);
                //do not pass token to task continuation- ensure serial execution between tasks.
                var continuationOfMoveNext = moveNextTask.ContinueWith((_) => { });
                await continuationOfMoveNext;

                if (moveNextTask.Exception != null)
                {
                    observer.OnError(moveNextTask.Exception);
                    return;
                }

                if (moveNextTask.IsCanceled)
                    return;

                if (moveNextTask.Result)
                {
                    observer.OnNext(cursor.Current);
                }
                else
                {
                    observer.OnCompleted();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            observer.OnError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            //TODO ensure cursor is not disposed by mongo on iteration end
            cursor.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you await on the continuation ? Awaiting the moveNextTask wasn't enough ?

Comment: It is a common pattern to do so, since in the case of an exceptions, await unwraps the first Inner exception in the resulting task's aggregate exception and rethrows it. This means that you lose the rest of the information within the aggregate exception in the case of a compound failure. The pattern you see avoids this end enables you to rethrow the aggregate.

Comment: This pattern should always be applied when awaiting code which is not under the caller's control- and to be honest - I went as far as creating a Resharper surround template for it - you never know how your own code may change one day.